# Long-haul flight departs one day before my visa validity starts, to land on the following day. Will I be denied boarding?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, long-haul

Need this help urgently please.
I will be travelling to Italy via Austria and Germany from 7th June, 2015 to 19th June, 2015 with my wife on my honeymoon.

My wife was granted her tourist visa on 28th May, 2015 by the Italian embassy In New Delhi. We would be landing in Europe (Munich) on 8th June, 2015 however our departure from Mumbai is on 7th June, 2015.

My wife has been granted her visa from 8th June, 2015. Would this be a problem at the Mumbai Immigrations at the airport because we are boarding the flight on 7th June and our visa is on 8th June?

Comment: The airline should understand that the visa will be valid when you land.  The Indian authorities would not care about the Schengen visa, as far as I am aware.  However, if I am wrong about that, they too ought to understand that the visa well be valid on landing.

Comment: Hope the title I edited is more verbose. Feel free to change it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your swift response. Makes me feel a little reassured. But who is the final authority on this ? How can I be sure that they will let me pass through the Indian immigrations ? Who should I contact to get a final word on this ? Flight is at 9.35 pm and the visa is valid from 12 midnight. Gosh !! 2 hours 25 minutes causing so much pain !! :(

Comment: Your answer would be better as a comment here. The answer you have is right, the airline and immigration will understand that this is OK and there shouldn't be a problem. If you're worried, and I understand why, then just call the airline and double check. I wouldn't worry about immigration, although you could always call the airport and ask to talk to someone in immigration, but they're really not going to care about where you're going. And, even if they do, they'll have seen cases like this before and it'll be fine.

Comment: Just an aside... "2 hours 25 minutes causing so much pain !! " I expect th evisa to be valid from 12:pm _CET_, so you _leave_ **6 hours** (5:55) before the visa is valid. That should still not be a problem as a direct flight from Delhi to Rome takes over 8 hours.

Comment: I am having the same question. Can you please post were you able to travel without any issues ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason it should be a problem. As far as Germany/the Schengen area is concerned, you need to have a visa which is valid when crossing the border checkpoint, at Munich airport, not before.

The airline will also check that you have a visa but it's not really a separate requirement, merely another verification that you meet the requirements of your destination country (because they can be fined if they bring people with no visa to the border point). Since your wife's visa would in fact be valid when she needs it, they should hopefully understand that it is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Outbound Immigration is not concerned with your destination, rather they are concerned that your stay in their country was valid.  And as a citizen you would have no issues there.  And even if they did look at the destination requirements aspect, they would see that the visa is valid for your intended trip.

The airline is the main factor in terms of you traveling, as they are the responsible party for verifying your permission to enter the destination.  But again as the visa will be valid when you arrive in the EU they would have no reason to deny boarding.  Of course this is assuming your departure is within the time period allowed by your visa.