# Next day visa - Wait five minutes to enter?

Tags: visas, air-travel, india

I have a visa for India valid from Monday.

There is a flight that arrives 23:55 Sunday night. Will airlines let me board?

Comment: It depends on the check-in agent. A reasonable one would understand you won't clear customs at least ten minutes if not more after landing. Somewhat similar question here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48611/long-haul-flight-departs-one-day-before-my-visa-validity-starts-to-land-on-the

Comment: What will you do when your flight arrives an hour early?

Comment: Walk very slowly.

Answer (score 6):

The answer was "No problem", at least for me.

Comment: Answer where? At the Airport?

Comment: No problem with the check-in agent at SFO. For arrival I hatched a brilliant plan, magically slowing my first leg down enough I misconnected, and will not be arriving until well into the visa's first valid day.

Comment: so, walk slowly from the gate to immigration counter worked :) ... BTW, which country/airport?

Comment: Was flying to BOM, missed connection in HKG.